# Margin-top wont work correctly

Tags: html, css

I want a button at 50% height of the page, but when I add style="margin-top:50%;" The button is placed at the bottom of the page....

Here is my code:

```css
html body {
  background: url("images/backgroundmkb.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body style=" margin:0; padding:0;">
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:50%;">
        <a href="startscherm">
          <center>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Terug naar start</button>
          </center>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use percentages of height with margin & padding. That is because the browser will calculate percentages based on the *width* of the parent, even for `-top` and `-bottom` properties.

Instead, you can use absolute positioning or flex.

## Absolute positioning

```
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

## Flex

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin-top:50%` to `margin-top:25%;`

```html
<style>
html body {
background:url("images/backgroundmkb.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
</style>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js">    </script>
 </head>
  <body style=" margin:0; padding:0;">
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:25%;">
     <a href="startscherm"><center><button class="btn btn-danger">Terug   naar start</button></center></a> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works, nice. But how is it possible that when I say margin-top: 50% The button is placed at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

```css
html body {
  background: url("images/backgroundmkb.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body style=" margin:0; padding:0;">
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner"> <a href="startscherm">
      <center>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Terug naar start</button>
      </center>
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
html body {
background:url("images/backgroundmkb.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
</style>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js">    </script>
 </head>
  <body style=" margin:0; padding:0;">
  <center style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;"><button class="btn btn-danger" style="height:50px; width:200px; margin-left:-100px; margin-top:-25px;">Terug   naar start</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if you can size your `div`:

Parent element should have this CSS:

```
height: 200px; //your size
line-height: 200px; //your size
text-align: center;
```

Button should have:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

---

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:grey">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height:200px;line-height:200px;text-align:center;">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" style="vertical-align: middle">Terug naar start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```